# Injective homomorphism from subgroup of $S_A$ to $S_A$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I need help with the end of this proof.
[image: end of proof]

If $G \le S_A$ why $\varphi$ turns out to be injective? I was trying to get to a contradiction assuming there exists $x\ne1$ such that $\varphi(x) = 1$. Then for any $a$ we have $\varphi(ax) = \varphi(a)\varphi(x) = \varphi(a)$ but I got stuck. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitional.  You start with "$G$ is a permutation group (i.e., $G \le S_A$)".  This means, as a matter of definition, that the only element of $G$ that does not move any elements of $A$ is the identity.  If the problem simply said "$G$ acts on $A$", this would not be the case.

By the way, there seems to be a typo in the last paragraph of quoted material, where it should say "...by previous exercise the kernel is $\cap_{g\in G}gG_ag^{-1}$".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why the homomorphism cannot be defined in such way that for a given $\sigma \in G$, $\sigma \ne 1$ we have $\varphi(\sigma) = 1$ ?

Comment: Are you having difficulty understanding the proof of 4.1.2, or are you saying you don't like the proof ans want to find a different proof?

Comment: No, sir. I am trying to understand why an homomorphism defined as $\varphi : G\le S_A \rightarrow S_A$ is always injective. You said that by definition the only element of $G$ that does not move any element of A is the identity. Then I asked why we cannot have $\sigma \ne 1$ such that $\varphi(\sigma) = 1$.